# Por qué da error Excepción (28) en placa NodeMCU?

Tags: arduino

al compilar mi codigo en la placa nodemcu v1.0 funciona un rato y luego me da excepción (28), alguna solución ? este es mi codigo, funciona un rato y luego deja de enviar datos al servidor, lo raro es en casa funciona perfectamente, pero con otros tipos de redes marca esa excepción, no se por que el error, debe ser error de codigo, vi que puede ser un bucle que se esta generando, por favor ayudar.
Estoy trabajando con un nodemcu basado en esp8266, las librerías son las 2.4.2 las baje de github, y con sensores dht11, higrometro y sensor de flujo y caudal de agua que trabaja con interrupciones.

## include

```
    #include <WiFiClient.h> 

    //-------------------VARIABLES GLOBALES--------------------------
    int contconexion = 0;

    const char *ssid = "Androidj7";
    const char *password = "Leica666";

    unsigned long previousMillis = 0;

    char host[48];
    String strhost = "192.168.43.72";
    String strurl = "/laravel-admin-template/public/enviardatos.php";
    String chipid = "";


    //-------Función para Enviar Datos a la Base de Datos SQL--------

    String enviardatos(String datos) {
      String linea = "error";
      WiFiClient client;
      strhost.toCharArray(host, 49);
      if (!client.connect(host, 80)) {
        Serial.println("Fallo de conexion");
        return linea;
      }

      client.print(String("POST ") + strurl + " HTTP/1.1" + "\r\n" + 
                   "Host: " + strhost + "\r\n" +
                   "Accept: */*" + "*\r\n" +
                   "Content-Length: " + datos.length() + "\r\n" +
                   "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + "\r\n" +
                   "\r\n" + datos);           
      delay(10);             

      Serial.print("Enviando datos a SQL...");

      unsigned long timeout = millis();
      while (client.available() == 0) {
        if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
          Serial.println("Cliente fuera de tiempo!");
          client.stop();
          return linea;
        }
      }
      // Lee todas las lineas que recibe del servidro y las imprime por la terminal serial
      while(client.available()){
        linea = client.readStringUntil('\r');
      }  
      Serial.println(linea);
      return linea;
    }

    #include "DHT.h"        // including the library of DHT11 temperature and humidity sensor
    #define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11

    #define dht_dpin 12 // PIN 6
    DHT dht(dht_dpin, DHTTYPE);
    #define sensorhigrometro A0 // PIN 0 Analogico

    int ENA = 4; // PIN 2
    int IN1 = 0; // PIN 3
    int IN2 = 2; // PIN 4

    volatile int pulsos; // Cantidad de pulsos del sensor. Como se usa dentro de una interrupcion debe ser volatile
    unsigned int litrosPorHora; // Calculated litres/hour 
    //int litrosPorHora;
    unsigned char sensorDeFlujo = 13; // PIN 7  Pin al que esta conectado el sensor
    //int sensorDeFlujo = 13;
    unsigned long tiempoAnterior; // Para calcular el tiempo
    unsigned long pulsosAcumulados; // Pulsos acumulados
    float litros; // Litros acumulados

    void flujo (){  // Funcion de interrupcion
    pulsos++; // Simplemente sumar el numero de pulsos
    }

    void setup(){
      dht.begin();
      pinMode(sensorhigrometro, INPUT);
      Serial.println("Humidity and temperature \n\n");
      Serial.println("==========================================");

      pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);

      pinMode(sensorDeFlujo, INPUT);
      Serial.begin(9600);
      attachInterrupt(sensorDeFlujo, flujo, RISING); // Setup Interrupt
      interrupts(); // Habilitar interrupciones
      tiempoAnterior = millis();

      Serial.print("chipId: "); 
      chipid = String(ESP.getChipId());
      Serial.println(chipid); 

      // Conexión WIFI
      WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
      while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED and contconexion <100) { //Cuenta hasta 100 si no se puede conectar lo cancela
        ++contconexion;
        delay(500);
        Serial.print(".");
      }
      if (contconexion < 100) {
          //para usar con ip fija
          IPAddress ip(192,168,43,238); 
          IPAddress gateway(192,168,43,1); 
          IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0); 
          WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet); 

          Serial.println("");
          Serial.println("WiFi conectado");
          Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
      }
      else { 
          Serial.println("");
          Serial.println("Error de conexion");
      }
    }

    void loop ()
    {
      unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
      if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= 10000) { //envia la temperatura cada 10 segundos
        previousMillis = currentMillis;  
      // Cada segundo calcular e imprimir Litros/seg
        // Pulse frequency (Hz) = 6.67 Q, Q is flow rate in L/min. (Results in +/- 3% range)
        // Q = frecuencia / 6.67 (L/min)
        // Q = (frecuencia * 60) / 6.67 (L/hora)
        pulsosAcumulados += pulsos;
        litrosPorHora = (pulsos * 60 / 6.67); // (Pulse frequency x 60 min) / 7.5Q = flow rate in L/hour
        pulsos = 0; // Reset Counter
        Serial.print(litrosPorHora, DEC); // Print litres/hour
        Serial.print(" L/hour");
        Serial.print(" Pulsos totales: ");
        Serial.print(pulsosAcumulados);

        litros = pulsosAcumulados*1.0/400; //Cada 400 pulsos = 1 litro
        Serial.print(" Litros: ");
        Serial.println(litros);


      int valorHumedad = map(analogRead(sensorhigrometro), 0, 1023, 100, 0);

      Serial.print("Humedad Suelo = ");
      Serial.print(valorHumedad);
      Serial.print("%,   ");

        float h = dht.readHumidity();
        float t = dht.readTemperature();         
        Serial.print("Humedad ambiental = ");
        Serial.print(h);
        Serial.print("%,  ");
        Serial.print("Temperatura = ");
        Serial.print(t); 
        Serial.println("°C  ");

        if(valorHumedad > 40){
            digitalWrite(ENA, 100); // set speed to 200 out of possible range 0~255
            digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
        }else{
            digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
          }

        enviardatos("chipid=" + chipid + "&temperatura=" + String(t, 2)+ "&humedadsuelo=" + String(valorHumedad) + "&humedadambiente=" + String(h, 2) + "&litros=" + String(litros, 3));
      }
    }
```